# Initialize Metamask from front-end use of Nodejs

Tags: web3js, metamask, nodejs

Building a simple ERC-20 Token payment screen for a simple shopping cart. I am having an issue figuring out how to use Metamask to allow others to make secure payments. As we dont have access to other users private keys, I must use Metamask as a helper for allowing payments. Nodejs being server-side, doesnt have access to Metamask. So does anybody know how I would go about prompting Metamask to sign and submit a transaction from a Nodejs view. JS script on the view page?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You would do this from JavaScript on the client (in the browser), not from Node.js.